# The array expression is not converted into a pointer When a string literal is used to initialize an array of characters

Tags: c

From C in a Nutshell:

> In  most  cases,  the  compiler  implicitly  converts  an  expression 
>   with  an  array  type, such as the name of an array, into a pointer to
>   the array’s first element.
>
> The array expression is not converted into a pointer only in the
>   following cases:
>
> • When the array is the operand of the  sizeof  operator
>
> • When the array is the operand of the address operator  &
>
> • **When a string literal is used to initialize an array of  char , 
>   wchar_t ,  char16_t , or  char32_t**

1. Could you explain what the last bullet means with some positive and
   negative examples? I don't find an example in the book for the last
   bullet.
2. Also why is an array of characters, not other element types?

Comment: Try compiling `char *str = "hello";` vs `char *str = {'h','e','l','l',o','\0'};`

Comment: @KeineLust Thanks. The type of `str` is a pointer type to char, not an array type. The quote talks about an array`.

Comment: oops, I misread the question: _The array expression is **not** converted into a pointer only in the following cases:_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *ptr = "Hello OP!!";
```

ptr is an pointer to first char of the string literal stored in the RODATA segment. When you dereference it you can only read but not write values as string literals are constant char arrays.

```
char arr[] = "Hello OP!! How are you my friend?";
```

In this case:

1. Is allocated space for the `arr` array of the length of size literal including the trailing zero.
2. String literal is copied into the space allocated for the `arr` array

In this case arr is used as place in the memory where the string literal is copied.

You can read and write as the arr elements are read & write

And now answering the question

- sizeof of an array is the size in bytes if all array elements. If the array was converted to pointer - the size would be the size of the pointer which is obviously wrong in this case
- Array is only the continuous space in the memory accommodating all its elements. So the address of the array is always the address of this memory location
- Third case i have explained above

you can see the code
https://godbolt.org/g/xVL5cR

** Note to TIM ** String literals are not converted to anything. String literal is only stored as a char (wchar_t ....) array with NUL (NOT NULL) teriminator at the end, in the RO memory.

Comment: In C in a Nutshell: "In `char *pStr = "Hello, world!"`, the string literal represents the address of its first element, just
as an array name would."

Comment: And it is exactly what I wrote - string literal is a bunch of nul terminated charcters. As a string literal is RO - it is stored (if hardware supports) in RODATA segment (memory which can be only read). This assignment char *x = "abcd";  assigns x with addres of the char 'a' in the string literal storage location.

Comment: What I edited is to clarify what "The array expression is not converted into a pointer" means in the third case when the array expression is a string literal.

Comment: If you do not like it I delete it

Comment: Unfortunately cant delete it

Answer (score 1):

> Why is an array of characters, not other element types?

Its becouse string literals have *static storage duration*, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

Attempting to modify a string literal(with pointer to literal) results in **undefined behavior**: they may be stored in *read-only storage* (such as `.rodata`) or combined with other string literals.

Any of other constants arent stored like this, so this is why only array of characters (literals).

> Could you explain what the last bullet means with some positive and
>   negative examples? I don't find an example in the book for the last
>   bullet.

String literal initialization looks like this:

```
char ptr[] = "Hello world!";     // This is char[]
char ptr[] = L"Hello world!";    // This is wchar_t[]
char ptr[] = u8"Hello world!";   // This is char[]
char ptr[] = u"Hello world!";    // This is char16_t[]
char ptr[] = U"Hello world!";    // This is char32_t[]
```

The string literal is copied from *static storage duration* to *automatic storage duration* and its possible to modify him.

While

```
char ptr[] = {'H','e','l','l',o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
```

wont be string literal and wont have *static duration storage*.

Comment: Your example of string initialization doesn't get at the OP's question and is actually pretty confusing. In that case the string literal _is_ converted to a pointer. I think you want `char s[] = "Hello world!";` This makes `s` an array of characters, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks. in the last example, how can you show that `ptr` the "array expression will be converted into a pointer"?

Comment: There are literals of other types, e.g. `(int[]){1, 2, 3}`

Comment: `char ptr[] = U"Hello world!";` is an error, the type of the array must match the initializer, e.g. `char32_t ptr[] = U"Hello world!";`. Same for other lines